# How to configure the TMC2208 Driver Voltage for a Creality Sprite Extruder in Klipper on Ender 3 Pro?

Tags: creality-ender-3, klipper, tmc2208

I'm trying to set up a Creality Sprite Extruder on my Ender 3 Pro without using the kit (installing the extruder alone).

I can see on the [Sprite Extruder Pro Kit product page](https://store.creality.com/products/sprite-extruder-pro-kit-300%E2%84%83-printing) that the extruder operates at 1.4 VDC and 0.8 A.

I'm using TMC2208 and Klipper. How can I set my extruder's driver up so that the provided voltage is 1.4 V? Is it the same as setting the VRef to 1.4 V?

Can it be done in the Klipper configuration (I have a UART set up), or does it need to be done on the trimpot?

Comment: have you gotten this figured out? I'm having extrusion issues with my sprite pro using the same drivers and I'm wondering if my VREF is too low or smth

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the voltages for stepper motors. TMC drivers drive the motors by controlling current, and as long as the current you select is not so high to burn the motor out, you're all good.

The voltage values listed have some physical meaning which I don't entirely understand, but in any case they are most definitely not the voltage the driver has at its disposal to move the motor and they're not anything you need to put in your configuration.